# Nested component refresh after edit

Tags: aem

Here is the issue I'm facing, I've got very simple component A and B, A is used inside of component B 
      using a data-sly-resource

I can edit the component A but I need to manually refresh the page or edit the component B if I want to see my change applied.

I tried to add the cq:listener, but no luck

```
<cq:listeners
    jcr:primaryType="cq:EditListenersConfig"
    afteredit="REFRESH_PAGE"
/>
```

Here is my .content.xml for A component :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0"
    jcr:description="component A"
    jcr:primaryType="cq:Component"
    jcr:title="Component A"
    allowedParents="[ */*parsys]"
    componentGroup="testComponent"/>
```

Here is my .content.xml for B component :

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <jcr:root xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" 
   xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0"
             jcr:primaryType="cq:Component"
             jcr:title="Component"
             componentGroup="testComponent"/>
```

Here is the cq:editConfig of component A

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0"
    cq:dialogMode="floating"
    jcr:primaryType="cq:EditConfig">
    <cq:listeners
        jcr:primaryType="cq:EditListenersConfig"
        afteredit="REFRESH_PAGE"/>
</jcr:root>
```

I'm using AEM 6.2.

Anyone who could help with this one ?

Thanks

Comment: This is weird since the your `cq:listeners` seem to be ok. It might help if you give us more information. What do the `.content.xml` files for both components look like? Is component `B` specifically defined as a container component? Can you post your whole `cq:editConfig`?

Comment: Component B is not defined as a container, how can I do that ? thanks for your answer

Comment: You have to add `cq:isContainer="{Boolean}true"` to component B. I don't know if that really helps but it might be the thing that is missing :)

Comment: I tried, no more luck

Comment: Can you please share your `cq:editConfig`?

Comment: sure here it is

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142732/discussion-between-jens-and-seb).

Answer (score 1):

In the cq:editConfig node of component A (which I understand to be the inner component), have you tried:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0" xmlns:nt="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/nt/1.0"
  jcr:primaryType="cq:EditConfig">
  <cq:listeners
    jcr:primaryType="cq:EditListenersConfig"
    afteredit="REFRESH_PARENT"/>
</jcr:root>
```

This will force the parent component B to refresh when editing component A. I'm using this approach for a custom Layout/Grid component.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and observed that component A (Inner component) is not properly initiated under content page structure when the page initially loads.

For example:

```
/content
     -my_page
         -jcr:content
           -root
              -Component B
                +Component A (this needs to be initiate)
```

So What I did simply added the "**cq:template**" and nested "**component A**" and set the component resources path with **sling:resourceType = {String}component-path**

This approach helped me to solve my issue :), try this way. cq:listener approach didn't work for me.